# jquery ui sortabble in groups

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I make a jquery sortable available in groups ?
(that is means that you can also sort it, interchange in other groups as well)

```
<div class="wpr">
<ul class="items1">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul class="items2">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Init();
});

function Init(){
    $( ".items1" ).sortable();
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/82tcjh32/)**

I just want to add, that I also have a draggable and droppable in this project. , which means that the droppable is also a sortable in those groups..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this....

```
$( ".items1" ).sortable({
        connectWith: '.items2'
    });
```

Or Use this..

```
<ul id="items1" class="items">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul id="items2" class="items">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

And the Script::

```
function Init(){
    $( "#items1" ).sortable({
        connectWith: '.items'
    });
    $( "#items2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: '.items'
    });
}
```

or

```
function Init(){
    $( ".items" ).sortable({
        connectWith: '.items'
    });
}
```

By this you can achieve..

Comment: A slight improvement : `$(".items").sortable({ connectWith: ".items" });`  [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/82tcjh32/1/)

Comment: yup we can do that too